# Spark with json4s, parse function raise java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

I wrote a function to process stream by spark streaming. And I encountered 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z

I have checked about the spark version(1.6.0) and scala version(2.10.5). It is consistent with json4s jar version(json4s-jackson_2.10-3.3.0.jar). I can not figure out what happened. And the following is the function code:

```
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read => JsonRead}
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

    def processStream(ssc: StreamingContext, windowStream: DStream[Array[Byte]], eventhubsId: Int): Unit = {
        /*
         ...
        */
        val successStream = eventsStream.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
        val successEventDataWindowStream = successStream.map(x => {
            val eventDataStr = x._2.getOrElse("")
            implicit val formats = jackson.Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
            Try(parse(eventDataStr).camelizeKeys.extract[EventData]) match {
                case Success(eventData) => Success(eventData)
                case Failure(ex) => Failure(ex)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/316

Comment: @KenjiYoshida It works when I change json4s version to 3.2.10. Thx!