# Spark-HBase - GCP template (3/3) - Missing libraries?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to test the Spark-HBase connector in the GCP context and tried to follow [the instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc), which asks to locally package [the connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/branch-2.4), and I get the following error when submitting the job on `Dataproc` (after having completed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466253/spark-hbase-gcp-template-2-3-version-issue-of-json4s)).

**Command**

```
(base) gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster $SPARK_CLUSTER --class com.example.bigtable.spark.shc.BigtableSource --jars target/scala-2.11/cloud-bigtable-dataproc-spark-shc-assembly-0.1.jar --region us-east1 -- $BIGTABLE_TABLE
```

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

Comment: Thanks for reporting and fixing it right after! I'm co-author of the demo so I'll use your work to fix it :)

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski: Thanks for your comment! Glad if it helps. Would you know if a connector to (Py)Spark 3.x is on the roadmap ?

Comment: I've got no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working way, by adding following dependencies in `build.sbt` - thanks [@jccampanero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13942448/jccampanero) for the guidance !

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "2.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-mapreduce" % "2.0.2"
```

**Output (`Bigtablesource.scala`)**

```
+------+-----+----+----+
|  col0| col1|col2|col3|
+------+-----+----+----+
|row000| true| 0.0|   0|
|row001|false| 1.0|   1|
|row002| true| 2.0|   2|
|row003|false| 3.0|   3|
|row004| true| 4.0|   4|
|row005|false| 5.0|   5|
|row006| true| 6.0|   6|
|row007|false| 7.0|   7|
|row008| true| 8.0|   8|
|row009|false| 9.0|   9|
|row010| true|10.0|  10|
|row011|false|11.0|  11|
|row012| true|12.0|  12|
|row013|false|13.0|  13|
|row014| true|14.0|  14|
|row015|false|15.0|  15|
|row016| true|16.0|  16|
|row017|false|17.0|  17|
|row018| true|18.0|  18|
|row019|false|19.0|  19|
+------+-----+----+----+
only showing top 20 rows

+------+-----+
|  col0| col1|
+------+-----+
|row000| true|
|row001|false|
|row002| true|
|row003|false|
|row004| true|
|row005|false|
+------+-----+

+------+-----+
|  col0| col1|
+------+-----+
|row000| true|
|row001|false|
|row002| true|
|row003|false|
|row004| true|
|row005|false|
+------+-----+

+------+-----+
|  col0| col1|
+------+-----+
|row251|false|
|row252| true|
|row253|false|
|row254| true|
|row255|false|
+------+-----+

+-----------+
|count(col1)|
+-----------+
|         50|
+-----------+
```